# Server Socket Issues [PHP]

Tags: php, sockets

The issues we came about was not the getting the client but retrieving the `Rndk` and on that point proceeding to the part that it retrieves a new client

```
    $this->logger->log("server", "A new client (ID: {$arrPenguin['id']}) has connected from {$arrPenguin['ip']}", "blue");
```

as you can see up top that should be displayed when it successfully gets the client.

Also, here are the functions that handles it

```
<?php
class ServerBase {

        public $settings;
        public $intServerId;
        public $logger;
        public $bubble_socket;
        public $arrPenguins = array();
        public $bubbler;

        public function __construct($settings, $intServerId, $loggerObject) {
            $this->settings = $settings;
            $this->intServerId = $intServerId;
            $this->logger = $loggerObject;
            $this->bubbler = new bubbler($settings);
            $this->status = true;
            return true;
        }

        public function startLoginServer() {
            $err = $this->bubbler->errors;
            $this->bubble_socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP) or die($err['SOCK_ERR1']);
            socket_set_option($this->bubble_socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1);
            socket_set_nonblock($this->bubble_socket);
            $status = socket_bind($this->bubble_socket, 0, @$this->settings['login_port']) or die($err['SOCK_ERR2']);
            socket_listen($this->bubble_socket, 5);
            usleep(0);
            if($status && isset($this->settings['login_port'])) {
                $this->logger->log("alert", "Server socket was opened! Listening on port {$this->settings['login_port']} in login mode... \n", "cyan");
            } else {
                $this->logger->log("error", $err['SOCK_ERR3'], "red");
                $this->bubbler->abort();
            }
            return true;
        }

        public function runLoginServer() {
            socket_listen($this->bubble_socket);
            while($this->status != false) {
                $this->listen();
            }
        }

        public function listen() {
            $read_bubble = array($this->bubble_socket);
            $x = null;
            socket_select($read_bubble, $x, $x, $x);
            if(in_array($this->bubble_socket, $read_bubble)) {
                $read_bubble[] = $this->newClient();
                $this->bubbler->continueLoop();
            }

            foreach($this->arrPenguins as $id => $class) {
                $sock = $this->getSockById($id);
                @socket_recv($sock, $strData, 8192, 0);
                if(isset($strData)) {
                    $this->handleSockData($strData, $id, $sock);
                } else {
                    $this->removeClientById($id);
                }
            }
            usleep(0);

        }

        private function getFirstCharacter($data) {
            return substr($data, 0, 1);
        }

        private function checkBadPacket($data) {
            $marker = false;
            if(!isset($data) || $data == "" || $data == " ") {
                $marker = true;
            }
            return $marker;
        }

        public function handleSockData($data, $id, $sock) {
            $err = $this->bubbler->errors;
            if(@isset($this->arrPenguins[$id])) {
                $arrPenguin = array();
                $arrPenguin['id'] = $id;
                $arrPenguin['sock'] = $this->arrPenguins[$id]->sock;
                $arrPenguin['ip'] = $this->arrPenguins[$id]->ip;
                if($this->checkBadPacket($data)) {
                    $this->logger->log("server", "{$err['BAD_PKT1']} by {$arrPenguin['ip']}", "red");
                    $this->removeClientById($id);
                }
                $strFirstChar = $this->getFirstCharacter($data);
                if($strFirstChar == "<") {
                    $this->handleXMLPacket($data, $id, $sock);
                } elseif($strFirstChar == "%") {
                    $this->handleXTPacket($data, $id, $sock);
                } else {
                    $this->logger->log("server", "{$err['BAD_PKT2']} by {$arrPenguin['ip']}", "red");
                    $this->removeClientById($id);
                }
            } else {
                socket_close($sock);
            }
            return true;
        }

        public function handleXMLPacket($data, $id, $sock) {
            $this->handleXMLData($data, $id, $sock);
        }

        public function handleXMLData($data, $id, $sock) {
            $arrPenguin = array();
            $arrPenguin['id'] = $id;
            $arrPenguin['sock'] = $this->arrPenguins[$id]->sock;
            $arrPenguin['ip'] = $this->arrPenguins[$id]->ip;
            if(isset($arrPenguin['id'], $arrPenguin['sock'], $arrPenguin['ip'])) {
                if($this->settings['development_mode']) {
                    $this->logger->log("received", $data, "purple");
                } else {
                    return true;
                }
                $this->parseXMLData($data, $id, $sock);
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }

        public function parseXMLData($data, $id, $sock) {
            $arrPenguin = array();
            $arrPenguin['id'] = $id;
            $arrPenguin['sock'] = $this->arrPenguins[$id]->sock;
            $arrPenguin['ip'] = $this->arrPenguins[$id]->ip;
            $arrPenguin['class'] = $this->arrPenguins[$id];
            $objPenguin = $arrPenguin['class'];
            if(isset($arrPenguin['id'], $arrPenguin['sock'], $arrPenguin['ip'])) {
                if($this->checkBadPacket($data)) {
                    $this->logger->log("server", "{$err['BAD_PKT1']} by {$arrPenguin['ip']}", "red");
                    $this->removeClientById($id);
                }
                if(strpos($data, "<policy-file-request/>") !== false) {
                    $objPenguin->send("<cross-domain-policy><allow-access-from domain='*' to-ports='*' /></cross-domain-policy>");
                    $this->removeClientById($id);
                }

                if(strpos($data, "<msg t='sys'><body action='verChk' r='0'>") !== false) {
                    $objPenguin->send("<msg t='sys'><body action='apiOK' r='0'></body></msg>");
                }

                if(strpos($data, "<msg t='sys'><body action='rndK' r='-1'></body></msg>") !== false) {
                    $objPenguin->send($this->generateRndK($data, $id, $sock));
                }
            } else {

            }
        }

        private function generateRndK($data, $id, $sock) {
            $len = 0;
            $string = "";
            $charBin = array(
                'A', 'B', 'C', 'D',
                    'E', 'F', 'G', 'H',
                'I', 'J', 'K', 'L',
                    'M', 'N', 'O', 'P',
                'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T',
                    'U', 'V', 'W', 'X',
                'Y', 'Z', 'a', 'b', 
                    'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 
                'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 
                    'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 
                'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 
                    's', 't', 'u', 'v', 
                'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 
                    '1', '2', '3', '4',
                '5', '6', '7', '8',
                    '9', '10', 
            );
            while(strlen($len) < 9) {
                $string .= array_rand($charBin, 1);
            }
            $RndK = $string;
            $RndKPacket = "<msg t='sys'><body action='rndK' r='-1'><k>" . $RndK . "</k></body></msg>";
            return $RndKPacket;
        }

        private function escapePacket($data) {
            $data .= chr(0);
            return $data;
        }

        public function sendBySock($data, $sock){
            $data = $this->escapePacket($data);
            $len = socket_send($sock, $data, strlen($data), MSG_EOR);
            if($this->settings['development_mode']) {
                $this->logger->log("sent", $data, "green");
            }
            return true;
        }

        public function removeClientById($id) {
            $err = $this->bubbler->errors;
            if(@isset($this->arrPenguins[$id])) {
                $this->logger->log("server", "Succesfully removed client #" . $id, "brown");
                socket_close($this->arrPenguins[$id]->sock);
                unset($this->arrPenguins[$id]);
            } else {
                $this->logger->log("server", $err['BAD_REMV_IP1'], "red");
            }
        }

        public function getSockById($id) {
            $penguin = $this->arrPenguins[$id];
            if(isset($penguin->sock)) {
                return $penguin->sock;
            }
        }

        public function getIpBySock($sock) {
            socket_getpeername($sock, $ip);
            $ip = "98.54.215.54";
            return $ip;
        }

        public function getUniqueClientId() {
            $count = 0;
            foreach($this->arrPenguins as $id => $a) {
                $count++;
            }
            $count++;
            if(!array_key_exists($count, $this->arrPenguins)) {
                return $count;
            } else {
                return $count++;
            }
        }

        public function newClient() {
            $id = $this->getUniqueClientId();
            $arrPenguin = array();
            $arrPenguin['id'] = $id;
            $arrPenguin['sock'] = socket_accept($this->bubble_socket);
            $arrPenguin['ip'] = $this->getIpBySock($arrPenguin['sock']);

            $this->logger->log("server", "A new client (ID: {$arrPenguin['id']}) has connected from {$arrPenguin['ip']}", "blue");
            $this->arrPenguins[$arrPenguin['id']] = new Penguin($arrPenguin, $this->settings);
            return $id;
        }
    }

?>
```

This was kind of hard to explain since i'm not sure anyone on StackOverFlow knows Club Penguins Protocol.

Comment: maybe interesting? [This wiki documents the workings of the Club Penguin protocol, used for communicating between the server and the client](http://protocol.clubpenguinwiki.info/wiki/Club_Penguin_Protocol).

Comment: I already looked at that and the problem has been resolved. Thanks anyways.